# Removing object from Group removes object from Scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a ThreeJS Group object that contains objects in the scene. I can add these objects fine and manipulate them independently, but whenever I try to remove an object from the group, it gets deleted from the scene.

```
var group=this.scene.getObjectByName(id);
for (var i=group.children.length-1; i >= 0; --i)            
    group.remove(group.children[i]);
```

Comment: Are you adding the entire group to the scene e.g `scene.add( group )` or each mesh individually? If you want meshes to still be visible after removing from group, you might want to add them individually.

Comment: I make the group like this: 
var group=new THREE.Group();            
group.name=id;                    
this.scene.add(group)

Then add members like this:
group.add(this.scene.getObjectByName(id)); They are actually groups I'm adding, which contain meshes

Comment: What happens is that once you remove that item from the group, it's not longer active on the scene. So you need to find a way to individually add each item to the scene. Regardless if they are meshes or groups.

Comment: hmmm. They are added one at a time initially. Do I need to re-add the removed item to the scene again using scene.add()?

Comment: Looks like I do need to re-add the object.

Comment: @BillFerster Imagine the scene and its groups are a tree. Only the objects which are part of this tree are rendered when something like `renderer.render(scene, camera)` is called. So I don't understand your question: *"Removing object from Group removes object from Scene"*- Of course, what do you expect?

Comment: I had assumed that adding an object group merely created a _link_ to the scene, not actually added it since the object I had added to the group was already a member of the scene tree. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify on the discussion in the comments of the question, there is actually little difference between a `Group` and a `Scene`. Both inherit `add` from `Object3D` ([`Object3D.add`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.add))

Here's some code showing how the adding/parenting works:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const group = new THREE.Group()
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(/*...*/)

// scene.children == []
// scene.parent = null
// group.children == []
// group.parent = null
// mesh.parent == null

scene.add(mesh)

// scene.children == [ mesh ]
// scene.parent = null
// group.children == []
// group.parent = null
// mesh.parent == scene

group.add(mesh)

// scene.children == []
// scene.parent = null
// group.children == [ mesh ]
// group.parent = null
// mesh.parent == group

scene.add(group)

// scene.children == [ group ]
// scene.parent = null
// group.children == [ mesh ]
// group.parent = scene
// mesh.parent == group
```

The part of `Object3d.add` that handles this is:

```
if ( object.parent !== null ) {

    object.parent.remove( object );

}
```

This ensures the object is parented to only one other object.

If your use-case is that you want your meshes directly in your scene, but still want to organize them using `Group` objects (so you can utilize functions like `getObjectById`), you can manually add them to the group's `children` array. Just remember that if you later choose to remove a mesh from the scene, it won't get garbage-collected until it's also removed from your group. Personally, I'd just use an array or a map.